# Swift 2.2: Recording swipe from one UIButton to another works slowly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview, uibutton

I have an `UIImageView` on a storyboard and through the `.swift` file, I have added several `UIButton` as subviews into this `UIImageView`.

What I want to do is, when I swipe from one of these `UIButton` to another `UIButton`, the software should record which one it is when I put my finger on the screen, and which one it is when I lift it up.

Everything works correctly. Except, I must do it slowly (ie touch down, and pause before moving my finger, then swipe to the other view, and then pause slightly before touching up). If I naturally do the swipe, it does not trigger the subview.

I do have a line drawn that traces my movement, and I can confirm I am hitting on the SubView.

Any advice for this?

Function for the touchdown event:

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    // Swipe trace
    stSwiped = false
    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {
        stLastPoint = touch.locationInView(swipeTraceDisplay)
    }

    let touch = touches.first
    let location: CGPoint = (touch?.locationInView(self.view))!
    let buttons: [UIButton] = mapDisplay.subviews as! [UIButton]

    for button in buttons {
        if button.pointInside(self.view.convertPoint(location, toView: button.viewForBaselineLayout()), withEvent: nil) {
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            selectedOriginUIButtion = button
            selectedOrigin = arrayMLegs[button.tag - tagOffset]
            hasSelectedOrigin = true
        }
    }
}
```

Function for the move event (this is irrelevant, but I'll put it on anyway):

```
    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    stSwiped = true
    if let touch = touches.first as UITouch! {
        let currentPoint = touch.locationInView(swipeTraceDisplay)
        drawLineFrom(stLastPoint, toPoint: currentPoint)
        stLastPoint = currentPoint
    }
}
```

Function for the touch up event:
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

```
       if (!stSwiped) {
        drawLineFrom(stLastPoint, toPoint: stLastPoint)
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 0, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.swipeTraceDisplay.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.swipeTraceDisplay.image = nil
    })
    let touch = touches.first
    let location: CGPoint = (touch?.locationInView(self.view))!

    let buttons: [UIButton] = mapDisplay.subviews as! [UIButton]

    if (!hasSelectedOrigin) {
        return
    }

    for button in buttons {
        if button.pointInside(self.view.convertPoint(location, toView: button.viewForBaselineLayout()), withEvent: nil) {

            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            selectedDestination = arrayMLegs[button.tag - tagOffset]

            UIView.animateWithDuration(1) {
                button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                self.selectedOriginUIButtion.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }

            makeEntry(selectedOrigin, destination: selectedDestination)

            hasSelectedOrigin = false
            return
        }
    }
    selectedOriginUIButtion.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    hasSelectedOrigin = false
}
```

Function for creating a button:

```
    func makeButton(label: String, posX: Int, posY: Int) {

    let pposX = CGFloat(posX) * 0.01
    let pposY = CGFloat(posY) * 0.01

    let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(pposX * imageWidth, pposY * imageHeight, 44, 44)
    button.setTitle(label, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
    button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    button.layer.borderWidth = 4
    button.userInteractionEnabled = false

    mapDisplay.addSubview(button)
}
```

Make the button's hit area larger:

```
extension UIButton {
override public func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let relativeFrame = self.bounds
    let hitTestEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, -20, -20, -20)
    let hitFrame = UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(relativeFrame, hitTestEdgeInsets)
    return CGRectContainsPoint(hitFrame, point)
}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It isn't totally clear what you're trying to accomplish here? Trace a line through a view with a pan gesture? UIButton probably isn't ideal...

Comment: No, I have an UIImageView with some UIButtons inside. I want to swipe from one UIButton to another, where the software will record which UIButton I touched I put my finger down and when I lift it up.

Comment: Is the entire imageView covered in buttons? Like you have a giant matrix of buttons? I'm not sure why its going slow, maybe because you're looping through every button there. I might be able to help by making a matrix of a UIView subclass that you can subscript and instantly grab the button it is inside. If you elaborate on exactly what you want to accomplish I can show you how I would do it. For example.. Do you want the touchDown button to turn green, the buttons swipedThrough to turn yellow, and the touchUp button to turn red?

Comment: Also, are all the buttons the same size? I have a matrix protocol that would work here with a little adjustment. Then just apply a transform to the point during the PanGesture and use the transformed x/y to grab the exact view it's in.

Comment: Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zzgpp87znlawbc3/WhatsApp%20Image%202016-09-27%20at%203.51.01%20PM.jpeg?dl=0

All the buttons are the same size. They are not positioned according to a matrix, just get the given x and y position (between 0 and 100, it's the relative position in percentage in the UIImageView).

Comment: Video demo doing it discretely: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vempls1y0lut9h4/demo.mov?dl=0

Video demo doing it naturally: https://www.dropbox.com/s/g7q4m90gihlrk2q/demofast.mov?dl=0

Comment: Yeah I would definitely not use UIButtons. I would subclass UIView, add a method called contains(point: CGPoint) -> Bool, this method quickly filters points too far away (x || y > radius) or already activate views(if active = true) else return pythagorean distance to center < radius. The UIView subclass then has an activate() method that changes the BG color and active to true and whatever else you need. Then in the pan gesture method, loop through the views, break if contains returns true and call active on that view. UIButton is a headache. I'll code this answer a bit later, just busy atm.